# Como imprimir etiqueta con lenguaje ZPL, con elementos rotados 180º

Tags: impresora, zebra, zpl

Necesito imprimir una etiqueta usando zpl ( impresoras zebra).

El primer 50% de la etiqueta que mide unos 50 cm está invertido o rotado 180º

el otro 50% de la etiqueta está en orientación original. Cuando lo mando a la impresora me devuelve el segundo 50%. La primera mitad la ignora por completo.

```
^XA
^MMT
^PW399
^LL4096
^LS0
^FT381,34^A0I,14,30^FH\^CI28^FD6 JUN - 035 - 0082000012^FS^CI27
^FT371,102^A0I,23,28^FH\^CI28^FDSN1234 SFO^FS^CI27
^FT288,52^A0I,23,35^FH\^CI28^FD^FS^CI27
^FT288,74^A0I,23,35^FH\^CI28^FD^FS^CI27
^BY2,3,67^FT230,58^BCI,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^FT381,138^A0I,16,30^FH\^CI28^FD6 JUN - 035 - 0082000012^FS^CI27
^FT371,210^A0I,23,28^FH\^CI28^FDSN1234 SFO^FS^CI27
^FT288,160^A0I,23,35^FH\^CI28^FD^FS^CI27
^FT288,182^A0I,23,35^FH\^CI28^FD^FS^CI27
^BY2,3,67^FT231,166^BCI,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^BY3,3,317^FT360,589^BCI,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^BY3,3,345^FT29,932^BCR,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^FO19,1332^GB375,2,2^FS
^FO20,1377^GB375,2,2^FS
^FT334,1349^A0I,24,41^FH\^CI28^FD0082 SN 000012^FS^CI27
^FO109,1376^GB2,473,2^FS
^FO18,1516^GB376,2,2^FS
^FO19,1661^GB375,2,2^FS
^FO19,1848^GB375,2,2^FS
^FT371,1482^A0I,14,15^FH\^CI28^FDVIA ^FS^CI27
^FT371,1626^A0I,14,15^FH\^CI28^FDVIA ^FS^CI27
^FT345,1692^A0I,30,51^FH\^CI28^FDSN1234^FS^CI27
^FT353,1756^A0I,68,89^FH\^CI28^FDSFO^FS^CI27
^FT131,1705^A0R,39,38^FH\^CI28^FD6 JUN^FS^CI27
^FT365,1868^A0I,16,23^FH\^CI28^FDTo: SFO Airport^FS^CI27
^FT144,1985^A0I,14,18^FH\^CI28^FDDOE/ JOHN^FS^CI27
^FO19,2202^GB375,2,2^FS
^FO273,2203^GB2,473,2^FS
^FT29,2192^A0N,16,23^FH\^CI28^FDTo: SFO Airport^FS^CI27
^FT206,2009^A0I,14,28^FH\^CI28^FDPNR XYZ123^FS^CI27
^FT91,2031^A0I,14,15^FH\^CI28^FDBRU^FS^CI27
^FO19,2714^GB375,2,2^FS
^FO20,2390^GB375,2,2^FS
^FT69,2706^A0N,24,41^FH\^CI28^FD0082 SN 000012^FS^CI27
^FO17,2530^GB376,2,2^FS
^FO19,2675^GB375,2,2^FS
^FT44,2371^A0N,30,51^FH\^CI28^FDSN1234^FS^CI27
^FT261,2331^A0B,39,38^FH\^CI28^FD6 JUN^FS^CI27
^FT49,2306^A0N,68,89^FH\^CI28^FDSFO^FS^CI27
^FT33,2440^A0N,14,15^FH\^CI28^FDVIA ^FS^CI27
^FT33,2588^A0N,14,15^FH\^CI28^FDVIA ^FS^CI27
^BY3,3,317^FT56,3452^BCN,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^BY3,3,345^FT378,3101^BCB,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^FT144,4018^A0N,14,20^FH\^CI28^FDBRU 6 JUN ^FS^CI27
^FT161,3997^A0N,14,15^FH\^CI28^FDDOE/ JONH^FS^CI27
^BY3,3,36^FT29,3978^BCN,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^FT29,3925^A0N,23,51^FH\^CI28^FD0082 SN 000012^FS^CI27
^FO60,3734^GB280,160,2^FS
^FT74,3798^A0N,23,23^FH\^CI28^FDSN1234^FS^CI27
^FT173,3798^A0N,23,23^FH\^CI28^FDSFO^FS^CI27
^FT256,3798^A0N,23,23^FH\^CI28^FD6 JUN^FS^CI27
^FT82,3838^A0N,23,23^FH\^CI28^FD^FS^CI27
^FT82,3871^A0N,23,23^FH\^CI28^FD^FS^CI27
^LRY^FO188,1735^GB176,96,96^FS^LRN
^LRY^FO33,2230^GB176,96,96^FS^LRN
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

He hecho múltiples pruebas con distintas etiquetas y no consigo que se imprima el 100% de la etiqueta

¿Alguien ha trabajado con esto previamente y se ha encontrado este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código ZPL esta correcto, sin embargo no estas considerando las condiciones de configuración de la impresora, si no que estás tomando los valores por defecto del equipo y por eso no respeta las medida que asignas al papel continuo.

Para poder hacer que tu etiqueta considere tus configuraciones del zpl y no las que tiene por defecto, es necesario enviarle ciertos comandos que indiquen el comportamiento que esperas de la impresora.

En esta caso Tienes que asignar el sensor de medios

```
^MN
```

Para indicarle a la impresora que tipo de papel enviaras (continuo o no continuo), en tu caso necesitas decir

```
^MNN
```

Donde el parámetro N indica que el papel el continuo y así te respete el parámetro `^LL4096`

Yo lo que hago es re-configurar todos los elementos cada que envío una impresión con el siguiente conjunto de comandos (para etiqueta continua, térmica directa)

```
~JSN^LT0^MNN^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0
```

En tu caso la respuesta quedaría así.

```
^XA
^MNN
^MMT
^PW399
^LL4096
^LS0 
...
```

o así:

```
^XA
~JSN^LT0^MNN^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0
^MMT
^PW399
^LL4096
^LS0 
...
```

Comment: Es exactamente eso. Lo he probado con el comando que indicas y funciona perfecto, muchas ganas por tu ayuda